# kubefwd doesn't work for specific ports/hostnames

Tags: kubernetes

I am using this command to run kubefwd (https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd)

`sudo kubefwd services -x <context> -n <namespace> -c <kube_file_path> -l "app in (idm, sbb-amq)"`

That is the log:

```
    INFO[14:13:58] Port-Forward: 127.1.27.1 sbb-amq:8161 to pod sbb-amq-0:8161
    INFO[14:13:58] Port-Forward: 127.1.27.1 sbb-amq:61616 to pod sbb-amq-0:61616
    INFO[14:13:58] Port-Forward: 127.1.27.1 sbb-amq:61616 to pod sbb-amq-0:61616
    INFO[14:13:58] Port-Forward: 127.1.27.7 idm:9006 to pod idm-0:9006
    INFO[14:13:58] Port-Forward: 127.1.27.7 idm:80 to pod idm-0:9006
    ERRO[14:14:01] ForwardPorts error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{80 9006}]
```

I got an error in the last line of the log, so I have realized that all the hostnames related to ports 80 and 9006 were not attached to the IP, which means:

- http://idm:9006 doesn't work
- http://127.1.27.7:9006 works

However:

- http://sbb-amq:8161 works as well (not using the port 9006)

Has anyone seen this before?

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu and the ports 80/9006 are not in use.

Answer (score 0):

`unable to listen on any of the requested ports`  usually means that you have something on your local workstation listening on those ports, `0.0.0.0:80` and `0.0.0.0:9006` in this case. The IP `0.0.0.0` means it's listening to those ports on all interfaces.

`kubefwd` uses local loopback IP addresses to allow the same port for multiple services so that you can have `127.27.1.1:80 -> someservice:80` and `127.27.1.2:80 -> someotherservice:80`.

Unfortunately, when you have local applications using `0.0.0.0:80`, you will not be able to bind 80 to any interface, as it is already being used. I don't know why applications often bind to every interface since `localhost` almost always points to `127.0.0.1`.

You have a couple of options:

1. change the configuration of those other services to use a single IP such as `127.0.0.1`
2. use the mapping flag and have kubefwd use a differnt port: `-m 80:8080 -m 9006:9007`